# Can I store textual fields in fact table of Datawarehouse?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, data-warehouse, fact-table

I have a fact table called **Fact_Employee_Ratings**, these are reviews about a company scrapped from Glassdoor. The review is actually divided into two parts, employees would give what they liked and what they disliked about the company. This is how I modeled the fact table but I'm not sure if I can include textual columns in the fact table "review_cons" and "review_pros" as follows because according to many websites, the fact table could only contain foreign keys and numerical measures :

fk_employee **(int)**

fk_publish_date **(int)**

review_pros **(varchar)**

review_cons **(varchar)**

engagement_score **(int)**

review_rating **(int)**

Comment: You can put any information you want in a fact table.  However, asking if it's useful to store certain information in a fact table is a valid question.  Is anyone ever going to query review cons across a district?  Over a 5 year period?  That's why your textbook says fact tables contain foreign keys and numeric values.

Comment: If the text contains analytically valuable content then I would extract that and model it into your star schema. Otherwise just keep in the long text values in a separate table and link them to your fact table as appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for @NickW 's suggestion and consider the following :

- Employee dimension: Contains information about employees (employeeSK,
  name, department)
- Review dimension: Contains details about the review    itself
  (reviewSK,review_pros, review_cons)
- Date dimension

Meanwhile in the fact table, you can still consider including measures such as the engagement_score,review_rating

JFY, this type of fact tables is called [transactional fact table](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2014/06/design-tip-167-complementary-fact-table-types/) since it focuses on capturing individual events or transactions within the business process.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by SK?

Comment: @HappilyCoding Surrogate Key.